# Not able to overload existing std::vector functions

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I am doing a POC implementation and as per requirement I need to extend `std::vector` insert API which would take only single parameter (value to be inserted) and internally the code would add this in the end of container.

I created a custom class (ValVector) derived from `std::vector` and defined a custom Insert API which accepts single parameter but while compiling it 
throws error.

Below is the snippet code with error message:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std; 

typedef bool BOOL;

template<class T, class Allocator = allocator<T>>

class ValVector : public std::vector<T, Allocator> {

  public: 
    BOOL insert(const T& elem) { return (this->insert(this->end(),elem)!=this->end()); }
 };

int main ()
{
  std::vector<int> myvector (3,100);
  std::vector<int>::iterator it;

  myvector.push_back (200 );

  ValVector<int> mKeyAr;

  mKeyAr.insert(10); // 

 std::cout << "myvector contains:";
  for (auto it=mKeyAr.begin(); it<mKeyAr.end(); it++)
    std::cout << ' ' << *it;
  std::cout << '\n';

  return 0;
}
```

Error Message:

```
In instantiation of 'BOOL ValVector<T, Allocator>::insert(const T&) [with T = int; Allocator = std::allocator<int>; BOOL = bool]': 
23:19: required from here 
11:72: error: no matching function for call to 'ValVector<int>::insert(std::vector<int>::iterator, const int&)' 
11:72: note: candidate is: 
11:10: note: BOOL ValVector<T, Allocator>::insert(const T&) [with T = int; Allocator = std::allocator<int>; BOOL = bool] 
11:10: note: candidate expects 1 argument, 2 provided In member function 'BOOL ValVector<T, Allocator>::insert(const T&) [with T = int; Allocator = std::allocator<int>; BOOL = bool]': 
11:88: warning: control reaches end of non-void function [-Wreturn-type]
```

Comment: +1, complete, minimal code, complete error description, concise description of the problem and why this is being attempted.

Comment: I'd better not to publicly inherit from `std::vector`, if I'm not wrong its destructor is not declared as virtual.

Comment: @burton0 - The non-virtual destructor is ok, as long as you don't delete a `ValVector` using a pointer to `std::vector`.

Comment: @BoPersson, you are right, but I'd prefer not to risk. Moreover, it seems to me that the public API of `ValVector` is so that it enforces the custom `insert` method as the privileged entry point to the vector. Maybe, it would be better to encapsulate a `std::vector` into `ValVector`, rather than inheriting.

Comment: How is this `insert` function different from `push_back`? (Other than returning a `bool`.)

Comment: This requirement doesn't look reasonable at all. Why would anyone want such a thing?

Answer (score 4):

To address your actual question: declaring a function in a class hides all inherited functions of the same name in that class. In other words, because `ValVector` has a function named `insert`, the inherited `std::vector::insert` is no longer visible in it. Probably the best way to solve this is to bring the inherited `insert` back to scope with a `using` declaration:

```
template<class T, class Allocator = allocator<T>>
class ValVector : public std::vector<T, Allocator> {

  public: 
    using std::vector<T, Allocator>::insert;

    BOOL insert(const T& elem) { return (this->insert(this->end(),elem)!=this->end()); }
};
```

---

However, I have a comment to make. I think your approach is wrong. `std` containers are not intended for public inheritance; if nothing else, they have no virtual destructor and no protected members. You'd be better off providing a free function, which could then be used with any `std::vector`, not just your type:

```
template <class T, class A>
BOOL insert(std::vector<T, A> &vec, const T &val)
{
  return vec.insert(vec.end(), val) != vec.end();
}
```

Or make it a bit more generic to work with any container:

```
temlate <class C, class E>
BOOL insert(C &cont, const E &val)
{
  return cont.insert(cont.end(), val) != cont.end();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you make your own insert member function for something which isn't virtual you hide all the same name functions from higher up (I think it's called shadowing).  You are now trying to call a function which is no longer visible.

Is there a good reason not to just make a separate function which does what you need, or do you have to derive this from vector?  Nothing you are doing requires access to protected data or functions...

```
// from
vector.insert(data);
// to
insert_poc(vector, data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change your insert implementation like follows for it to work

```
    BOOL insert(const T& elem) { return (std::vector<T>::insert(this->end(),elem)!=this->end()); }
```

Cheers